# Calling virtual function from destructor of an inner class

Tags: c++, destructor, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

I have a set up that looks like this

```
class A
{
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    extern "C" A* getSingleton(); 

    class B {
        B() { getSingleton()->doSomething(); }
        ~B() { getSingleton()->doSomething(); }
    };
};

class C : public A
{
    static A a;
    extern "C" A* getSingleton() { return &C::a; }
    void doSomething() { //things }
    // also has a container of Bs that will be added to and removed from regularly
}
```

Which crashes with a '__cxa_pure_virtual' during the destructor, but not the constructor. C::a is defined correctly in a different file omitted for brevity

I have read that calling virtual functions from ctors/dtors is usually a bad idea, however in this case it will make the usage of B nicer so am interested in getting it to work safely. Can anyone explain why B's ctor manages to do this dodgy action but the dtor can't, and then how can I rework this properly?

Comment: You misunderstood what you read. Calling virtual functions of a class `A` inside the c'tor/d'tor of  `A` itself is the problem (either directly or indirectly). Since `B` is an entirely separate class (it's just defined inside `A`), there's no inherent issue in calling virtual functions of `A` in its constructor.

Comment: VTC: missing the definitions of `C::a` and the B objects, which are critical to determine order of execution. We can't explain invisible code.

Comment: There are well-established ways of implementing singletons. This is not one of them. Find one with your search engine of choice.

Comment: What is this code even trying to accomplish?

Comment: How are you declaring an instance of an abstract class? Or is there more code you've not show?

Comment: How are you sure that the crash is due to '__cxa_pure_virtual' during the destructor call only but not the constructor?

Comment: How are objects of class `B` created- if there exists a global object, then it may be destroyed before or after `C::a`.

Comment: The posted code cannot even compile. Please post REAL CODE.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order of execution.

In C++ objects are created from top to down.
What does it mean?

When you have a class X and Y.
The class Y inherit from X.

X = "father"
Y = "son"

When you instantiate an object of type Y, and put some print on the constructor and destructor, you will see that first the constructor of X is called, then the constructor of class Y.

The destruction is (of course) in inverted way.
First is called the destructor of Y, then the destructor of class X.

Knowing that, then we look to the OO problem that you have:
Calling a **virtual pure** method in the destructor of the X class (father).
When the destructor of X class is executed, the Y (son) **object** doesn't exist anymore.

So: how can the X object find the virtual pure method, that should be implement in the inherited class/object?

Comment: What you say would be true if the pure virtual method were being called in the destructor of X, but that is not the case in the OP's example. The method is being called in the destructor of Z, which is not related to X or Y in any way, other than it is nested inside of X but not actually tied to X's lifetime.